# storing a user defined class in a map with the member as the key

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct

this is what im trying to accomplish, i want to create a user defined project struct and then store it in a map using the project name as the key. i am probably being a noob but can someone tell me what im doing wrong, when i try and compile the program it spits out a bunch of bizarre output, so it looks like its not working, what should i do?

```
map<project, string> provec;

project current;

cout << "Enter your project name: ";
current.proname = getFileContents(cin);

cout << "Enter a description: ";
current.prodesc = getFileContents(cin);

cout << "How long until deadline: ";
current.protime = getFileContents(cin);

provec.insert(pair<project, string> ( current, current.proname ));
cout << endl << "You created a new project: " << current.proname
<< endl << "Project description: " << current.prodesc ;
```

Comment: Didn't you mean it the other way round - string (project name) as key, `project` instance as value? It doesn't make much sense as written.

Comment: If you really want to map projects to names like this, just add a member called `name` into the project class but you already have that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to switch this:

```
map<project, string> provec;
```

to this:

```
map<string, project> provec;
```

right?

In this case, you'd be mapping the name of the project, to the project itself.

Comment: ok so i got it working , my mistake was that i flipped the key and the mapping value

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::set instead and provide a special comparator to use proname as a key:

```
typedef std::set<project, []( const project &p1, const project &p2 ) { return p1.proname < p2.proname; } > provec;
```

Or you can override operator< for your class `project`. Downside of this solution is that you will have to create temporary `project` to do lookup.

Another solution would be to use `boost::multi_index`

Issues with solution with std::map:

- Data duplication
- Nothing stops you to put different stings for key and field proname in the map, or replace that object later, so it is more error prone.